# How to unlock the boot partition in GParted

Tags: boot, partitioning, gparted

First of I am a total noob in Ubuntu and have never used a Linux-based system before.
Just to give you an image of how little knowledge I have:
I am at the point where I am trying to understand the "Terminal" concept. I've used it to install programs and type in certain commands.

To the question:

I bought a Notebook that had Ubuntu installed and right now I am trying to create a Windows partition. I got GParted running, but unfortunately my boot partition is somehow locked (there's a key symbol in front of the name). I'd like to unlock it and format it to NTFS.
The 3 installed partitions are:

1. dev/sda1 ... FAT32 ... 10GiB ... hiden,lba..............unlocked->I could format this one
2. dev/sda2 ... EXT4 ... 452.16GiB ... boot.................locked-> this one I'd like to format to NTFS
3. dev/sda3 ... linux-swap ... 3.6 GiB

[image]

I tried to format it from the Windows CD, but the "format" option was locked.

I treid the command line:

```
umount /dev/sda2
```

as root, but only got back:

```
umount: /: device is busy.
        (In some cases useful info about processes that use
         the device is found by lsof(8) or fuser(1))
```

Thx 4 the help!

Comment: screenshot: upload the image and Ill make it a picture.

Comment: THX a lot! http://i.imgur.com/p4Ga3FG.png

Comment: your main partion can't be NTFS on linux, and should not be NTFS. NTFS is a closed windows based file system and the open implementation of it are terribly slow. Please think about what you're trying to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- There is no reason for boot to be NTFS if you want both Ubuntu and Windows. The problem you face is that Microsoft wants the Windows operating system as the FIRST operating system on the disc.

The easiest method to fix this is to format all discs, make 2 partitions where the 1st one is NTFS and the 2nd one EXT4 and then install Windows on the 1st and Ubuntu on the 2nd.
This will get you a GRUB with both Ubuntu and Windows in the menu.

- If you do want boot to be NTFS you will also want [GRUB4DOS](https://gna.org/projects/grub4dos/). So you will need to install that 1st. But this will NOT fix your problem of installing Windows. Grub demands support for permissions and symolic links and NTFS does not provide that so it is not possible for boot to be NTFS when using GRUB.

Comment: Thanks man, this explains a lot...follow up question: How can I format all discs in ubuntu? Is there some command line I have to type into the terminal. Is there a way to format the discs outside of ubuntu, say in BIOS?

Comment: No, no. Just use the partition tool in the installer from Windows. From Windows delete all parts. Then make 2 parts, 1 NTFS, other unallocated. Install windows in NTFS. Install Ubuntu in the unallocated one. It is very simple once you have seen it 1 time ;)

Comment: DUDE, if there was any way to send beer over the internet, I'd send you a gallon right now! THanks a thousand times!

Comment: Eeeeeww beer :D Coca Cola for me

Comment: Then so it be! ;)